# how to create a custom SELinux label

Tags: linux, fedora, security, selinux

I wrote a service/single binary app that I'm trying to run on Fedora 24, it runs using systemd, the binary is deployed to `/srv/bot`

this service/app I wrote needs to create/open/read and rename files in this directory.

I first started creating a new policy based on [SELinux: allow a process to create any file in a certain directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88622/selinux-allow-a-process-to-create-any-file-in-a-certain-directory/90761#90761)

but when my app needed to rename, the output had a  warning:

```
#!!!! WARNING: 'var_t' is a base type.
allow init_t var_t:file rename;
```

I googled around and I found out I should use a more specific SELinux label than a base type, but all the examples online show you existing labels from httpd/nginx/etc.

Is there a way I can create a custom label just for my own app?

My idea is to create something like myapp_var_t, use

```
semanage fcontext -a -t my_app_var_t '/srv/bot(/.*)?'
restorecon -R -v /srv/bot
```

and a custom `.pp` file that will use this custom type

If there is a better way to solve it, that works too.

Thanks

#### Update

After more searching around I think the proper term for what I want to do is to create new `types` which led me to 
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html#id3036916

which basically says, run

```
sepolgen /path/to/binary
```

and I was able to get a template that I can then compile into a pp file and load, still get some errors but looks like I'm closer to what I want to do.

If I get it to work, I'll update this post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the starting point of running

```
sepolgen /path/to/binary
```

which gives you:

```
app.fc
app.sh
app.if
app.spec
app.te
```

To create a new `SELinux file context` to apply to a parent directory that holds files your program/daemon will modify, you edit the app.te file and add :

```
type app_var_t;
files_type(app_var_t)
```

The first line declares the new type and the second line calls a macro that does some magic and makes it a file type (turns out you cannot use a process context line app_exec_t on a file or directory), see ["SELinux Types Revisited"](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/54803.html) for more info on the different types

Once you have the type declared, you need to tell SELinux that your app is allowed to use it, in my case I added

```
allow app_t app_var_t:dir { add_name remove_name write search};
allow app_t app_var_t:file { unlink create open rename write read };
```

Those two lines basically say, allow the app_t type which is the domain  of my app, to write/search/etc directories with the context `app_var_t` and allow it to create/open/delete/etc files with the context app_var_t

The last part of the puzzle is to somehow tell SELinux which folder(s) and file(s) should get each type, you do this by editing the `app.fc` file (fc => file context)

this file only has two lines in my case:

```
/srv/bot/app        --  gen_context(system_u:object_r:app_exec_t,s0)
/srv/bot(/.*)?          gen_context(system_u:object_r:app_var_t,s0)
```

the first line points straight to the binary as deployed on my servers, so this one gets the app_exec_t context.

The second line means:

> Apply app_var_t to the directory /srv/bot and also to all files inside the dir /srv/bot

Note how the first line has `--` between the path and the call to `gen_context`. `--` means, apply this to only files. on the second case we don't have anything (just spaces), which means, apply to all matching directories and files, which is what I wanted, another option is to have `-d` to apply just directories.

I now have a working policy, I can deploy my app with a custom policy and it all works. (my policy has a lot more entries in the `.te` file but it is outside the scope of this question.)

Extra reading material that helped me get to this solution:

[Making things easier with sepolgen](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html#id3036916)

[Think before you just blindly audit2allow -M mydomain](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/69958.html)

[SELinux FOR RED HAT DEVELOPERS](https://www.redhat.com/en/files/resources/en-rhel-selinux-devlopers-120114.pdf) (Long PDF)

[An SElinux module (1): types and rules](http://equivocation.org/node/27)

[Sample policy (specially the postgresql)](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/refpolicy/tree/master/policy/modules/services)

[Understanding the File Contexts Files](https://web.archive.org/web/20151020104623/https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/SELinux_Guide/rhlcommon-section-0037.html)

Comment: Or use [CIL](http://blog.siphos.be/2015/06/where-does-cil-play-in-the-selinux-system/)

Comment: `sepolgen /path/to/binary` spits out a syntax error for me.  I'm on RHEL 7.6.  I think `sepolgen --application /path/to/binary` is the proper syntax if your goal is to write a policy for a particular application??

Comment: Your `.te` file also throws a syntax error for me when compiling the module: `app.te:5:ERROR 'This block has no require section.' at token 'files_type' on line 5:`.  And if I add a `require` section, I get: `ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'files_type' on line 13:`

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have access to a Fedora machine to test it, but it could be that since version 24, they changed the syntax.