# SELinux: How do you create a custom label for files?

Tags: selinux

According to this link,
[how to create a custom SELinux label](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309122/how-to-create-a-custom-selinux-label),
they show that you can use sepolgen on `/path/to/binary`.

But what if I'm not working on a binary? I want to make my directory to become a `test_type_t` type, which means I will have to create a `test_type_t` and then use `chcon` or `semanage` to change the type of that directory.

How do I create the `test_type_t` so that I can change the type of my directory?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create your own custom policy for that in a directory create a `mylocalpolicy.te` with the following content:

```
policy_module(mylocalpolicy, 0.0.1)

type test_type_t;
files_type(test_type_t)
```

Then you can run in the same directory: `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile`. This will generate a .pp file that you can load with `semodule -i mylocalpolicy.pp`

Please not that nothing will be able to interact (read/write/delete/…) with files with this label.