# Use selinux for path based access

Tags: path, selinux, access-control

Consider the following scenario. I've a ro file system mounted at `/system` and I can't remount it rw at all. There is a file `/system/bin/xyz` with context `u:r:bin_t`. Naturally I cannot change the context as file system is ro. I have a program running with context `my_prog_t` which needs to execute `/system/bin/xyz`. Now I can allow `my_prog_t` to execute `bin_t` but I don't want it to execute other `bin_t` files as well. In apparmor this can be done with file path. Can this situation be handled with selinux without resorting to apparmor?

Comment: Have you tried `audit2allow` ? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux

Comment: It 'suggests' allow my_prog_t bin_t: file {open read getatyr execute stat}. Which I don't want as said in question.

Comment: Check this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309122/how-to-create-a-custom-selinux-label

Comment: I the volume in which the xyz program is, is readonly. How am I supposed to change context there. Also I know how to make contexts.